# Powershell debugging in Visual Studio Code: Watch for Hashtable does not show useful info

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code, hashtable

I'm using Visual Studio Code to debug a Powershell script. I have a Hashtable object called $SCRIPT:studentInfo. When I add a Watch for this Hashtable in the Debugger, I find that the Watch doesn't  display any useful information.
[image: Variable Watch only shows object type, not contents.]

Is there any efficient method to get useful information about the entire contents of a Hashtable while I am debugging?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just watch for `$studentInfo`?

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. Really kicking myself that I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered by Daniel in the comments: Remove the SCRIPT scope qualifier (ie. watch '$studentInfo' instead of '$SCRIPT:studentInfo') and the Watch displays contents of the Hashtable as expected.